# Facebook Messenger notifications no longer showing up

Tags: notifications, facebook

I'm not sure what caused it, but notifications for Facebook Messenger on my iPhone 8 are no longer showing up anywhere (no badges, app icons, or notifications of any kind). However, when I open the Messenger app, I guess it triggers something as at that point it at least updates the badge icon:

[image]

I've enabled all notification settings I can think of, yet still no notifications.

In the Messenger app:

[image]

[image]

And under Settings > Notifications > Messenger:

[image]

I'm on the latest version of iOS (14.3) and my Messenger app is up to date (294.0). This seems to be specific to the Messenger app as I receive notifications from other apps (e.g. Messages, Slack) just fine.

Comment: Have you tried signing out of fb and then reinstalling the app?

Comment: Re-installing the app made no difference. I can't sign out of the Messenger app. Are you suggesting I sign out of the Facebook app?

Comment: Yup I would try that.

Comment: Same problem, did all upgrade, factory upgrade, etc... Still here!

Comment: For posterity: I have a new iPhone now and no longer have this issue. I never resolved my original problem on my previous phone.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the Messenger App then re-download
the Messenger App.
Open the Messenger App then look to the
bottom left of the screen and a red circle in
under Chat.
Click on Chat for the unread message to appear.
Open Facebook and the notification will be clear.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I have no problem seeing unread messages in the app, nor having the unread messages notification clear when I read any unread messages. I do not need to open Facebook to clear any notifications (I don't understand the point of that step). Re-installing Messenger also doesn't resolve my actual issue.